# How can I find the lift on the first decile after running a classification tree (in R)

Tags: r

I have run the following classification tree on the ebayAuctions dataset and am trying to find the lift on the first decile.  below is the code I have used but it somehow doesn't make sense, even the deciles don't add up to 10! I have a feeling the problem is in my 
gains() function but not sure how to fix it. Would somebody please help me.

```
class.tree <- rpart(Competitive. ~ .,
                    data=train.df,
                    method="class",
                    parms=list(split="information"),
                    control=rpart.control(minsplit=1),
                    xval =10 #10 fold cv
)

Pred.val <- predict(class.tree ,valid.df,type = "class")
treeScore<- predict(class.tree,valid.df,type = "prob")


library(gains)
gain <- gains(valid.df$Competitive., treeScore[,2])
gain

# plot lift chart
plot(c(0,gain$cume.pct.of.total*sum(valid.df$Competitive.))~c(0,gain$cume.obs),
     xlab="# cases", ylab="Cumulative", main="", type="l")
lines(c(0,sum(valid.df$Competitive.))~c(0, dim(valid.df)[1]), lty=2)
# compute deciles and plot decile-wise chart
heights <- gain$mean.resp/mean(valid.df$Competitive.)
midpoints <- barplot(heights, names.arg = gain$depth, ylim = c(0,3),
                     xlab = "Percentile", ylab = "Mean Response", main = "Decile-wise lift chart")
# add labels to columns
text(midpoints, heights+0.5, labels=round(heights, 1), cex = 0.8)
```

Thank you very much

My Decile chart looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaYXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without giving a plot, the function `TopDecileLift()` might give you the answer you're looking for:

```
TopDecileLift(predicted_rf, validation$Competitive.)
[1] 1.264
```

Comment: Thank you riv.  I tried the same on a random forest but I get different values: for randomForest:1.624. and for single classification tree: 1.762.   Would you know if/how I can apply this to boosted or bagged trees?